# setting up reverse proxy for fisheye/crucible using apache

Tags: apache, atlassian-crucible

I am trying to setup reverse proxy using apache for fisheye/crucible
However, I am getting:

Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the configuration files:

end of the httpd.conf file

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so


<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPass  / http://fisheye.example.com:8060/
ProxyPassReverse / http://fisheye.example.com:8060/
```

config.xml

```
<web-server site-url="http://fisheye.example.com" context="/">
     <http bind=":8060" proxy-host="fisheye.example.com" proxy-port="80" proxy-scheme="http"/>
</web-server>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Apache 2.4+ you probably want to change `Allow from all` to `Require all granted` - See https://serverfault.com/a/549559/71216